# How do I add more "elements" or "dimensions" to a single dimension array?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I hope I am wording my question the right way, and using the correct terminology.  I have an array of student names, `arrSummary`, that is distinct (no duplicates).

Then, I have another array, `arrTest1`, that contains a list of the same students' names and their test scores on Test1.  Then I have a third array, `arrTest2`, that contains a list of their names and their test scores on Test2.

`arrTest1` and `arrTest2` are such that `arrTest1[0].Name = "Bob"` and `arrTest1[0].Score = "98"`.

How do I make the array, `arrSummary`, such that `arrSummary[0].Name = "Bob"`, `arrSummary[0].Score1 = "98"`, `arrSummary[0].Score2 = "76"`?

There are different types in the array (string, integer, integer).

Comment: Why not have arrSummat list of student class as well?

Comment: You can use the Linq Join statement to combine two lists.

Comment: Avoid Hungarian Notation (e.g. prefixing array variable names with "arr").

Comment: Hi David.  Can you please explain why I should avoid Hungarian notation?  I need a reason/explanation behind the command to do so.

Comment: Are you looking to restructure your application completely, so as to eliminate your existing three arrays, or are you just looking to create a fourth array that combines the data from the existing three arrays?

Comment: Hi Dax, the latter.  But with a twist,  I was hoping I could glom on information from the 2 test score arrays onto the arrSummary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var arrSummary = arrTest1.Join(arrTest2, person => person.Name, person => person.Name
    , (first, second) => new
    {
        Name = first.Name,
        Score1 = first.Score,
        Score2 = second.Score,
    })
    .ToArray();
```

Note that this is querying the first two arrays and creating a brand new array.  Here I used an anonymous type for the query result; if the query results will be used outside of this method you'll want to make a new class with those 3 properties and project the results to instances of that type (just put that type after `new`).

You can't change the dimensions, the type, or even the size of an array once it is created.  If the summary array already is of a type that has all three properties then you could in theory go through and populate it, but it would probably be easier to just generate the summary array from scratch, which is why that's what I've done here.

Answer (score 0):

Use a single list or array that stores data as fields in a class rather than three different arrays, like so:

```
class TestResult {
    public String Name;
    public Int32 TestResult1;
    public Int32 TestResult2;
}

TestResult[] testResults = new TestResult[ numberOfStudents ];
testResults[0].Name = "Mr. Foo bar";
testResults[0].TestResult1 = 65;
testResults[0].TestResult2 = 76;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a type and use that in your array:

```
public class TestSummary {
  public string StudentName {get;set;}
  public int Score1 {get;set;}
  public int Score2 {get;set;}
}
```

*OR*

You could do this the RIGHT way:

```
public class Score{
   public int TestId {get;set;}
   public int StudentId {get;set;}
   public int Score {get;set;}
}

public class Student{
   public int ID {get;set;}
   public string FirstName {get;set;}
   public string LastName {get;set;}
   public List<Score> Scores;
}
```

Then you should have a `List<Student>` instead of your summary array thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
var scores1 = arrTest1.ToDictionary(score => score.Name);
var scores2 = arrTest2.ToDictionary(score => score.Name);
var output = arrSummary.Select(name=>new {Name=name, Test1 = scores1[name], Test2 = scores2[name]).ToArray();
```

(Note this only works if your arrTest arrays don't have any missing entries.  i.e., there's no names in arrSummary that aren't in arrTest1 or arrTest2.)

Comment: You'll want to set the value of the two dictionaries to be the `Score` property, or you'll need to fetch the `Score` property out of the type in the `Select`.  (I prefer the first option).

Answer (score -1):

Create a class or struct that contains the data you want to store and create an array of those objects! Better yet you may consider using a List!

```
public class Student
{
    public string name {get;set;}
    public int score1 {get;set;}
    public int score2 {get;set;}
}
```

...

```
List <Student> = new List<Student>();
List.Add({name="Len", score1=90, score2=100});
```