# Is it possible to bind an array to DataGridView control?

Tags: c#, winforms, binding

I have an array, arrStudents, that contains my students' age, GPA, and name like so:

```
arrStudents[0].Age = "8"
arrStudents[0].GPA = "3.5"
arrStudents[0].Name = "Bob"
```

I tried to bind arrStudents to a DataGridView like so:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = arrStudents;
```

But the contents of the array do NOT show up in the control.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Along with what others have written, I'd be inclined to use a `BindingList<T>` so that changes to the underlying data would be visible in the `DataGridView`.

Comment: Check this: https://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Binding-Arrays-to-GridView-in-ASP-Net-With-Code-Examples

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As with Adolfo, I've verified that this *works*. There is nothing wrong in the code shown, so the problem must be in the code you aren't showing.

My guess: `Age` etc are not public properties; either they are `internal` or they are *fields*, i.e. `public int Age;` instead of `public int Age {get;set;}`.

Here's your code working for both a well-typed array and an array of anonymous types:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class Student
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public double GPA { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

internal class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main() {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        using(var grid = new DataGridView { Dock = DockStyle.Fill})
        using(var form = new Form { Controls = {grid}}) {
            // typed
            var arrStudents = new[] {
                new Student{ Age = 1, GPA = 2, Name = "abc"},
                new Student{ Age = 3, GPA = 4, Name = "def"},
                new Student{ Age = 5, GPA = 6, Name = "ghi"},
            };
            form.Text = "Typed Array";
            grid.DataSource = arrStudents;
            form.ShowDialog();

            // anon-type
            var anonTypeArr = arrStudents.Select(
                x => new {x.Age, x.GPA, x.Name}).ToArray();
            grid.DataSource = anonTypeArr;
            form.Text = "Anonymous Type Array";
            form.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Marc.  I'm confused.  What am I doing wrong, and why isn't the contents of my array showing up in the DataGridView?

Comment: @phan what is the exact type of `arrStudents`, and what does `Student` look like ?

Comment: Well, the exact type can be found in the answer I chose for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321842/how-do-i-add-more-elements-or-dimensions-to-a-single-dimension-array.  "arrSummary" in that solution s what my arrStudents array is like.  If I can bind the arrSummary in that question to a DataGridView I would be happy as well.

Comment: @phan the code in your accepted answer is an anonymous type; which in c# does not have writeable properties, so it is inconsistent with the code shown in your question. I've also played with this using anonymous types, and it *still works*.

Comment: Marc, if you add the following ".OrderBy (item => item.Age);" to your anon-type Array will it still work for you ie publish to the DataGridView?  Just curious.

Comment: @phan that depends; is it still an *array* at the end? or is it just an *enumerable* ? i.e. is it `.OrderBy(...)`, or is it `.OrderBy(...).ToArray()` ?

Comment: It is the former.  Not the latter.  Btw, thank you for taking the time to help explain this to me.

Comment: @phan then ***that is the problem***; data-grid-view binds to the `IList` API; an array implements `IList`; however, the thing you get from `OrderBy(...)` *does not* implement `IList`. So ***that is why it  didn't work***. So basically, the real problem here is that you lied about the question: you stated: "I have an array, arrStudents", that you showed as `dataGridView1.DataSource = arrStudents;` - when actually that ***is not*** accurate. That *would have worked*. If you had asked the question accurately, people would have been able to answer it must more quickly and accurately.

Comment: Wow, the lightbulb went off in my head.  Thank you Marc!!!  There was no intention to "lie".  I honestly described the problem as I saw it, but my understanding of it is, as you can see, wrong.

Answer (score 10):

This works for me:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public double GPA { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public Form1()
{
        InitializeComponent();

        Student[] arrStudents = new Student[1];
        arrStudents[0] = new Student();
        arrStudents[0].Age = 8;
        arrStudents[0].GPA = 3.5;
        arrStudents[0].Name = "Bob";

        dataGridView1.DataSource = arrStudents;
}
```

Or less redundant:

```
arrStudents[0] = new Student {Age = 8, GPA = 3.5, Name = "Bob"};
```

I'd also use a `List<Student>` instead of an array since it will have to grow most likely.

Is That what you're doing too?

[image]

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't work. I used an ArrayList though and filled with elements of a class I derived. Does this matter?

Comment: Figured it out. I was using public members for the class instead of properties. Weird though!

Comment: Will this automatically add elements to the list when the user includes new lines?