# DataGridView doesn't display the data

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have an Access table which I want to display on a DataGridView, but the GridView doesn't display the data.

All the other functions inside this one works properly.
This is the function:

```
    private void ShowSuppliersFrm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dgvShowSupps.RowCount = dataB.GetSuppliersNumber();
        dgvShowSupps.ColumnCount = 3;

        dgvShowSupps.Columns[0].HeaderText = "SuppNumber";
        dgvShowSupps.Columns[1].HeaderText = "SuppName";
        dgvShowSupps.Columns[2].HeaderText = "SuppPhone";

        Supplier[] supplierList = dataB.GetSupplierData();
        int size = supplierList.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            dgvShowSupps[0, i].Value = supplierList[i].SuppNumber;
            dgvShowSupps[1, i].Value = supplierList[i].SuppName;
            dgvShowSupps[2, i].Value = supplierList[i].SuppPhone;
        }


    }
```

This is my table:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuIBD.png]

Comment: WPF? Windows Forms? ASP.NET? Xamarin?

Comment: Thanks for the response,c#.

Comment: "*C#*" doesn't answer dymanoid's question - WPF, WinForms, ASP.NET, and Xamarin all use C# as a code base.  That said, WPF doesn't use DataGridView objects, and my guess is you're programming in a WinForms project?

Answer (score 0):

Normally with a datagridview, you would simply do this:

```
private void ShowSuppliersFrm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var binding = new BindingSource();
    binding.DataSource = dataB.GetSupplierData();
    dgvShowSupps.DataSource = binding;        
}
```

It can be a DataTable or a list of objects. Though you may have to do some data marshalling or setup on the DataGridView if it shows data that you don't want.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That better explain it?

Comment: But if you google Bind list of objects to DataSource. You'll find lots of examples doing just this.

Comment: Here's another, similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323596/is-it-possible-to-bind-an-array-to-datagridview-control

Comment: Thanks alot! but I still can't make it work for some reason.

Comment: Try this. It may be that it wants a binding source. it's been a year or so since I've done this.

Comment: glad to hear it. been a while since I've done that. Can you accept the answer if it works?

Comment: ofc just tell me what to do

Comment: Should be a button next to the answer. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work