# Display data of a class that is in another class datagridview c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a class that contains data from another class:

```
class SecondClass
    {
        public FirstClass element { get; set; }
        public string note { get; set; }
    }
```

Then I create a list of class elements and display it in the datagridview.

```
firstarray.Add(new FirstClass() { id = 1, name = "name", password = "text" });

            foreach (var item in firstarray)
            {
                if (item.id == 1)
                {
                    secondarray.Add(new SecondClass() { element = item, note = "text" });
                }
            }

            foreach (var item in secondarray)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.element.id);
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = secondarray;
```

And I get the wrong output of the items. How do I fix this?

[image: https://prnt.sc/11n3023]

Comment: You say you get the _"wrong output of the items"_ but you don't say what you actually want the output to be? However if you want to see anything other than the type of `FirstClass` then you have to override `ToString()` in that class, for example you could return the `name`.

Comment: @stuartd After I created the code `public override string ToString() {return id + name + password; }` it worked correctly. But how do I output each value to a separate column?

Comment: To do that you need to get each value into the data source so it shows as a column. You could expand `SecondClass` or alternatively project the data into an anonymous type and use that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to bind an array to DataGridView control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323596/is-it-possible-to-bind-an-array-to-datagridview-control)

Comment: @stuartd Thanks for the advice. But most likely I need to create a class that will include data from two classes. Because I do not need to use all the data to display in the datagridview, but I need all the other data to work in the code.