# How to assign values to multiple form controls?

Tags: c#, forms, for-loop, textbox, text-files

I have lots of textboxes on a form that I want to fill in with lines I have saved in a text file. I have the text file be read and save every line into an array. Then I want to set each line equal to a corresponding text box.

I currently have it all saved line by line like this:

```
            string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("savedWorkout.txt");      
            textBox1_1.Text = lines[0];
            textBox1_2.Text = lines[1];
            textBox1_3.Text = lines[2];
            textBox1_4.Text = lines[3];
            textBox1_5.Text = lines[4];
            textBox1_6.Text = lines[5];
            textBox1_7.Text = lines[6];
            textBox2_1.Text = lines[7];
            textBox2_2.Text = lines[8];
            textBox2_3.Text = lines[9];
            textBox2_4.Text = lines[10];
            textBox2_5.Text = lines[11];
            textBox2_6.Text = lines[12];
            textBox2_7.Text = lines[13];
```

I have tried to use a for(i = 0; i < 7, i++) loop, replacing each number in the text box name with i, but I am unsure on how to do this correctly, if possible. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you want to use a `for` loop you'll need to prepare an iterable (like array, List etc.) holding all your `TextBox`es.

Comment: Any specific reason to use `TextBox` and not a `ListBox`? You could display the lines in a `ListBox` and on click offer a `Textbox` for editing?

Comment: After you drag the textbox to the form, you should always change its name to something meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

The textbox names have two numbers. With `i` being the index in the `lines` array, the first one can be calculated with

```cs
int n1 = i / 7 + 1;
```

The second one with

```cs
int n2 = i % 7 + 1;
```

Together

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++) {
    int n1 = i / 7 + 1;
    int n2 = i % 7 + 1;
    Controls[$"textBox{n1}_{n2}"].Text = lines[i];
}
```

Consider using a DataGridView instead.

See also: [Is it possible to bind an array to DataGridView control?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12323596/880990).

Answer (score 0):

The following reads lines from a file, dynamically creates a TextBox for each line on to a panel named panel1 were panel1 AutoScroll is set to true so if there are more lines than real estate a scrollbar will be used.

As presented in the screenshot, the width may need to be adjusted to accommodate the text width for the lines.

Place this class into your project

```
public class TextBoxOperations
{
    public static List<TextBox> List { get; set; }
    public static int Top { get; set; }
    public static int Left { get; set; }
    public static int Width { get; set; }
    public static int HeightPadding { get; set; }
    public static string BaseName { get; set; }
    public static Control ParentControl { get; set; }
    private static int _index = 1;
    public static void Initialize(Control pControl, int pTop, int pBaseHeightPadding, int pLeft, int pWidth)
    {

        ParentControl = pControl;
        Top = pTop;
        HeightPadding = pBaseHeightPadding;
        Left = pLeft;
        Width = pWidth;
        List = new List<TextBox>();

    }
    private static void Create(string text)
    {

        var button = new TextBox()
        {
            Name = $"{BaseName}{_index}",
            Text = text,
            Width = Width,
            Location = new Point(Left, Top),
            Parent = ParentControl,
            Visible = true,
            Tag = _index
        };


        List.Add(button);

        ParentControl.Controls.Add(button);
        Top += HeightPadding;
        _index += 1;

    }

    public static void Build(string[] lines)
    {
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            Create(line);
        }
    }

    public static void Save(string fileName)
    {
        File.WriteAllLines(fileName, List.Select(tb => tb.Text).ToArray());
    }
    
}
```

Form code with a panel and two buttons, first button loads lines, second provides a method to save the lines to the same file.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly string _fileName = "savedWorkout.txt";
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        panel1.AutoScroll = true;
    }

    private void RunSampleButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(_fileName);

        TextBoxOperations.BaseName = "LineTextBox";

        TextBoxOperations.Initialize(panel1, 20, 30, 10, 400);
        TextBoxOperations.Build(lines);

    }

    private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBoxOperations.Save(_fileName);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I have now added the textboxes into an array and tried to use a loop as such: for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++)
            {
                exercises[i] = lines[i];
            }  but it doesn't seem to be updating the textboxes